# What Cokin Filter system do I need for my setup?

Tags: filters, cokin

I'm getting into my landscape photography a lot more and struggling with exposures, so it's time to get a filter system.

I own an array of lenses; `EF17-40mm`, `EF100-400mm`, `EF50mm f/1.4` & `100mm Macro`. I use these on my `Canon EOS 6D`.

What filter system should I go with? I don't want to spend hundreds right now so I'm looking at `Cokin`, however I'm not sure what filter mount I should get for my array of focal lengths.

Any help is appreciated,
Andy

Comment: What are the filter thread sizes for those lenses?

Comment: 77 on wide angle, 77 on 100-400, 58mm on the 50mm prime, 62 on the macro.

Comment: The thing I was worried about most was the field of view on the lenses. I used to have an old P system from cokin, but on my old APS-C Nikon, the edge of the frame was creeping into shot, and with the 6D being a full frame AND the wideangle being 17mm at it's lowest, I don't want to get it wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On all of the lenses you list but the EF 17-40mm f/4 L you could get by with the Cokin P series which uses 84mm filters. For wide angle lenses with 72mm filter threads Cokin [recommends](https://www.cokin-filters.com/resources/V4056A-COKIN_BROCHURE_56P-weblow.pdf) using the Cokin Z-Pro Series which uses 100mm filters.

Based on several online reports, including [this thread](https://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/2757740), from those who have tried the standard P series holder with the EF 17-40mm f/4 L you'll get vignetting at focal lengths shorter than about 20mm with a FF camera. The Cokin "wide angle" holder that is thinner and only holds a single filter does a bit better but still vignettes slightly at 17mm. Since the filter holder is thicker on the sides than on the top and bottom, turning the filter holder 90° will reduce the vignetting, but that limits your ability to use rectangular graduated ND filters.

Keep in mind that the EF 17-40mm f/4 has fairly significant light loss in the corners at 17mm and f/4 even when there is absolutely nothing attached to the front of it. How much more you're willing to tolerate caused by the filter holder could also factor into your decision.

Comment: Thanks for this Michael. Going to be a tough decision I think, I don't want to spend too much but I don't want the vignetting really. Although I don't really shoot often at 17mm-20mm, you never know

Comment: Here's another link that might help: http://www.fredmiranda.com/forum/topic/1110012